# Accordion on sharepoint 2013 depending on User Permission

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-server, quick-launch

For my Quick Launch jquery Accordion, I used this link :
http://sharingtothepoint.blogspot.ch/2013/10/how-to-make-accordion-menu-for-subsite.html
Everything works fine because I'm the administrator of the farm. But when I add users to groups and they have permissions on subsites, the jquery doesn't work anymore.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to work around running with privilages in JQuery using SPServices.  You can use the GetGroupCollectionFromUser function and if they belong to the group, run your accordion in the function.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

isGroupMember("My Permission Group", function(result){
if(result){

    runAccordionFunction();    }

});



function isGroupMember(groupName, callback)
{
$().SPServices({
     operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
     userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
     async: true,
     completefunc: function(xData, Status) {

callback( !!($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='" + groupName + "']").length) ); /*returns bool */
     }
  });
}

</script>
```

This might work for you as a workaround.  Let me know if this helps.  Good Luck!